# Is there any differences between this two ways of looping and which one is preferable to be used?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, lambda

I was coding under netbeans 8.1 I was using a `for` loop and I was curious to see what will the IDE suggest as code formating, so my original loop was :

```
    List<Produit> produits = pjc.findProduitEntities();
    for (Produit produit : produits) {
        System.out.println("p ="+produit.getTitre());
        observableArrayList.add(new FXProduit(produit));
    }
```

I got finally two suggestion that I want to understand if they are the same or there is some performance or memory management differences.

the first suggestion was named `use functional operation based on lambda expression`:

```
    List<Produit> produits = pjc.findProduitEntities();
    produits.stream().map((produit) -> {
        System.out.println("p ="+produit.getTitre());
        return produit;
    }).forEach((produit) -> {
        observableArrayList.add(new FXProduit(produit));
    });
```

the second one uses the `inner class paradigm`

```
    List<Produit> produits = pjc.findProduitEntities();
    produits.stream().map(new Function<Produit, Produit>() {
        @Override
        public Produit apply(Produit produit) {
            System.out.println("p ="+produit.getTitre());
            return produit;
        }
    }).forEach((produit) -> {
        observableArrayList.add(new FXProduit(produit));
    });
```

Comment: [read this](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297162/why-should-i-use-functional-operations-instead-of-a-for-loop)

Comment: @Omore that very helpfull, your comment is an answer

Comment: Thanks keep learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anonymous class version is the least attractive, because it creates a new class and new instances with every invocation that require garbage collection.

The stream version can be cleaned up and improved considerably using `peek()`, parallel stream and method references:

```
pjc.findProduitEntities().parallelStream()
    .peek(produit -> System.out.println("p ="+produit.getTitre()))
    .map(FXProduit::new)
    .forEach(observableArrayList::add);
```

I have assumed that parallel processing is OK, since the objects end up in an observable context, in which order makes no difference. Even without the parallel stream (ie just using `.stream()`) the code is still a lot cleaner.

Comment: thank you Bohemian, I learned lot from this answer, I want to search in google for tutorial that explain how do the "::" works but unfortunately I don't know how we call this, at first glance this is pretty feel like the reflection. do the new will call a constructor that matches the parameter, that also feels like Spring 1 way of thinking ( and maybe I'm not right due to my lack in english). please provide me with keywords for my research

Comment: The `::` is a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). Yes, constructors can also be referenced using `::new`, and yes the `.map()` method expects a `Function`, which accepts the element type of the stream and returns something else, which is what a constructor that accepts the element does.

Comment: Even if the order is irrelevant, that doesn’t imply that `observableArrayList.add` is thread safe. In fact, that is rather unlikely. Combine that with the fact, that this operation will most probably not benefit from parallel processing at all…